# Use AngularJS to add 30 days to current date and update days calculated when calendar value changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, calendar

I have an AngulaarJS application where users select the day they want to view and it prints on the calendar the day and the next 30 days. The intended functionality needs to be so that when a user changes the day from the calendar it needs to show that day followed by the next 30 days.

As it stands my application shows todays date and the next 30 days but doesn't update the calendar when I change days on the date picker.

I am using the Angular Material datepicker:

```
<md-datepicker md-placeholder="Enter date" ng-model="myDate" ng-change="date_generator()" md-open-on-focus>
</md-datepicker>
```

This is the HTML I am using to print out the data:

```
<tr ng-repeat="date in futureDates">
    <td>
        {$ date | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' $}
    </td>
```

And then my Angular function is:

```
$scope.date_generator = function() {
    $scope.currentDate = $scope.myDate;
    $scope.startDate = $scope.myDate; // Current moment
    $scope.endDate = new Date($scope.myDate.getTime() + 30*24*60*60*1000); // Current moment + 30 days
    $scope.iDate = new Date($scope.currentDate); // Date object to be used as iterator
    $scope.futureDates = new Array();
    $scope.futureDates.push( $scope.iDate.setDate($scope.iDate.getDate() - 0));
    while ($scope.iDate <= $scope.endDate) {
        $scope.futureDates.push( $scope.iDate.setDate($scope.iDate.getDate() + 1)); // Switch to next day
    }
}
```

Currently [this is how the results look like](http://prntscr.com/edowbi)

What am I doing wrong and what do I have to do to make the days on the calendar change whenever I change the date on the Date Picker?

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, did my answer help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tweaked your HTML a little and it worked for me:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="date in futureDates">
    <td>
      {{ date | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Here's a working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/L67sy555/.

Comment: Sorry for late response, that worked great, thanks a bunch. Mind telling me what was wrong with my HTML? Can't really tell the differences in HTML code

Comment: `{$`, should be, `{{`.  And, `$}`, should be, `}}`.

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely suggest using a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

With it you could easily manipulate your dates without too much manual stuff (where things could always go wrong).

For example to add 30 days to a date:

```
console.log(moment().add(30,'d'));
```

Moment objects can also be added or subtracted (in example to your end and future date variables).